# Pixel location (x,y coordinate) from the image when image is resized

Tags: c#, winforms, matrix

I want the pixel location(x,y co-ordinate) from the image actual scenario is

1) when fit the image into picture box it gives me an correct x,y pixel co-ordinate using mouse pointer it gives me correct pixel co-ordinate.

but

2) when i re-size the image and get the pixel co-ordinate it of that image it shows me wrong pixel co-ordinate.

while search on google some of refer me to use Matrix class of Microsoft .net but didn't know how to use it to get location the pixel location(x,y co-ordinate) while the image is resize?

if possible give me source of reference.....

Comment: Which x/y coordinate are you looking for? Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: @jacob actually when I resize the image into picture box and user click over the image at any location(inside image) just that time i want that pixel co-ordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Using a matrix is overkill. Given an image's original size and new resized dimensions, you should be able to do some simple math to translate a pixel in the resized image to a region in the original image:

```
// Given origWidth, origHeight, newWidth, newHeight, clickX, and clickY variables...
var scaleX = (double)origWidth / newWidth;
var scaleY = (double)origHeight / newHeight;
var translatedRegion = new {
    X = clickX * scaleX,
    Y = clickY * scaleY,
    Width = scaleX,
    Height = scaleY
};
```

Note that I'm not translating to a pixel, but to a region, because one pixel may not translate to just a single or even a whole pixel in the original.